# TemplateRef and click event

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-template

I have a common template for different components but some buttons. So, I create a common component and change this buttons with ng-template:

```
<component-common 
       [buttonTemplate]="buttonTemplate">
</component-common>

<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-element="element" let-method>
  <button (click)="method">
        element.name              
  </button>
</ng-template>
```

In component-common.component.ts:

```
export class ComponentCommonComponent {

   @Input() buttonTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

   constructor() { }

   test() {
      console.log("test called");
   }
}
```

and in html:

```
<ng-template 
    *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate;context: {method: test(), element:element}">
</ng-template>
```

The proble I found is "test" is called all the time, and I just want it to be called when clicking, what are I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
{method: test(), element:element}
```

To

```
{method: test, element:element}
```

You don't want to call the method instead you just need a reference of method.

Also in template you should be using `let-method="method"` and call it as `method()`:

```
<ng-template ... let-method="method">
  <button (click)="method()">
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5bwqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: it does nothing, no error but not message, could I miss something else?

Comment: Check console log. It prints `test called` on button click.

Comment: thanks! that was my missing point, adding () in template it works!

Comment: Only add that if "test" function is not so easy as "console.log" and use the component "this" change {method:test} by {method:test.bind(this)}